# How to search using a part of string in splunk and group by

Tags: search, contains, splunk

I need to create a report to show the processing time of certain events in splunk and in order to do that I need to get get all the relevant events and group by a id.

My current splunk events are like

```
{
  "Timestamp": "Mon Sep 01 18:19:42 CDT 2020",
  "Id": "567",
  "Application": "TEST"
},
{
  "Timestamp": "Mon Sep 01 13:19:42 CDT 2020",
  "Id": "567-test-00-10",
  "Application": "TEST"
},
{
  "Timestamp": "Mon Sep 01 10:19:42 CDT 2020",
  "Id": "567-test-03-10",
  "Application": "TEST"
},
{
  "Timestamp": "Mon Sep 01 15:19:42 CDT 2020",
  "Id": "567-test-01-10",
  "Application": "TEST"
},
{
  "Timestamp": "Mon Sep 01 08:19:42 CDT 2020",
  "Id": "567-test-02-10",
  "Application": "TEST"
}
```

I need to get the latest and oldest timestamps to create the report and I am having difficulty grouping them by the id.

My idea is to get the first part of the id and group them together but I not able to achieve this.

I tried `basesearch |eval id= mvindex(split(id, "-"),0)  |stats last(Timestamp) as latestTime by id*` which isn't working.

I need to show `id,late(Timestamp),first(Timestamp)` in the report. I would really appreciate any help

Comment: Is that JSON? Is it properly coming-into Splunk? Is data arriving into Splunk via HEC or some other means?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `split` will do if the hyphen is not found so here's another query to try.

```
base search | rex field=id "(?<id>\d+)"
| stats latest(Timestamp) as latestTime, earliest(Timestamp) as earliestTime by id
```